# Sinch, is there any limitation on instant messages?

Tags: sinch

Is there any limitation on Sinch instant messaging, e.g. total size, frequency? Can I send json?

Besides, how instant is it? is it implemented in websocket, or webRTC, or hybrid? thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We recommend that you only send messages that are at most a couple of kilobytes in size. You can send JSON in the message itself. There's no frequency limit.

How instant it is depends on network connection on each side - it's transmitted over HTTP.

Comment: is it possible to send binary data? or I have to b64 encode it first?

Comment: We recommend only sending short text messages, which is reflected by the SINOutgoingMessage methods taking NSStrings and the Android WritableMessage taking a String to set the message body

Comment: "short" is kind of vague. how about under 8k in size?